# How to delete attributes in XForms?

Tags: orbeon, xforms, xforms-betterform

I know about `xf:delete` element which is used to delete a nodeset. However, I just want to delete some attributes. Is there a way to do it?

I am using XSLTForms as the XForms implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xf:delete>` applies to all node types, not only elements. So you can also use it to remove attributes:

```
<xf:delete ref="foo/@bar">
```